# Unable to access Webmin through browser

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, server, webmin, virtualmin

I followed DigitalOcean's tutorials on how to set up your server with SSH, creating a new user, firewalls etc. The first tutorial in the series is linked under:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-connect-to-your-droplet-with-ssh

I've also installed Webmin on my server, but I still can't get a connection to the server by using the web-browser. It just loads for a long time and then says it can't establish a connection. The URL's I've been using are:

"Just-my-IP-adress" and "https://Just-my-IP-adress:10000"

The last one to open the Webmin administrator.

I'm not sure what else needs to be done to get a response from the server. This is all new to me, so you shouldn't assume that anything besides the tutorial I followed above has been done.

Any rookie-mistake-suggestions would be appreciated.

**UPDATE1**: After following this tutorial to install LAMP, I now get a response when just using my IP-adress, webmin is still not responding, but I assume it was not properly installed since I did not have LAMP installed when I did the Webmin-installation.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu

**UPDATE1**: After installing Webmin again, I still can't access it through the browser. I tried the command:

```
nc -zvw 3 <my-ip> 10000
```

in the terminal and got this as a response:¨

```
Connection to <my-ip> 10000 port [tcp/webmin] succeeded!
```

So I guess the port is open and I should be able to connect to it, but it won't let me use the GUI in the browser.

Comment: I got this working recently, so maybe I can help you out: "it won't let me use the GUI in the browser." What do you see in the browser?

Comment: @ValerieAsensio It says that the page is not available and that the connection timed out.

Comment: I checked your port 80 and see you have the default Ubuntu setup, but your 10000 seems to be non-functional as you mentioned. Run this command on the linux box: "netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN" and see which ports are set to listen. If you would, post the results.

Comment: @ValerieAsensio 10000 is also set to listen after checking with your command, I set it to listen manually too, just to be sure.

Comment: @ValerieAsensio It's also set to tcp, I don't know if that matters.

Comment: tcp is correct. Does the nestat line resemble this? "tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10000           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN"

Comment: There's another thing to check. Webmin if installed properly, should set up a virtual host for itself. Without that host enabled, webmin won't fire even if the port 10000 is  listening.  Look in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/. Is there a webmin site .com.conf virtual link there?

Comment: @ValerieAsensio I went to the directory and typed in "ls" but there is only one file there "000-default.conf"

Comment: I have the same problem - webmin/virtmin was working fine, did some work, rebooted the system, and now can't get to the server.domain:10000. Reinstalling webmin didn't fix the problem.

Comment: I have the same issue, webmin worked well on Ubuntu 18.04, after upgrading to  Ubuntu 20.04, I cannot access Webmin page via browser any more, but port can be seen by typing command "netstat -a" in terminal, weird?!

Comment: Make sure you are not running on vpn as well

Answer (score 37):

Please try to restart webmin with the following command and check if you are getting any error.

```
/etc/init.d/webmin restart
```

If it's working fine, Then defiantly there is an issues with the firewall OR some ports are blocked at your DC end. Please try to stop firewall and check again.

Comment: after restarting I could access webmin. May be something had to reconfigure.

Comment: You can also restart with "service webmin restart".

Answer (score 20):

## It will solve your problem

1. `nano /etc/webmin/miniserv.conf`
2. now change `ssl=0` into `ssl=1`.
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save it.
4. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to exit the `nano`.
5. Now restart webmin `service webmin restart`

**Cheers**.

Comment: Thanks! I just had to do the other way around, change ssl=1 into ssl=1.

Comment: @nicozica what you changed ssl=1 to ssl=1 ? is not that the same?

Answer (score 16):

Digital ocean sets up your basic firewall with the '1-click' LAMP stack. All ports but ssh and http are blocked. I think the tutorial has you setting that up as well.

Run `sudo ufw status` to see what ports are currently allowed

and then `sudo ufw allow 10000/tcp` to allow access to the one webmin needs.

Answer (score 8):

try this ... it's working for me

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 10000 -j ACCEPT
service iptables save
/etc/init.d/iptables restart
```

open both link in Browser

https://your-IP:10000
and
http://your-IP:10000

Answer (score 2):

Try:

`sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -d 0/0 -s 0/0 --dport 10000 -j ACCEPT`

Answer (score 1):

Port 10000 is listening so, so you either have a Webmin installation problem, or the SSH may be creating a problem for Webmin.

I would recommend disabling the SSH, going back to non-SSL. Check and see if port 10000 is Webmin GUI? If not, purge Webmin install.

```
apt-get --purge remove webmin
```

Reinstall Webmin using the instructions from Webmin

http://www.webmin.com/deb.html

With SSH still disabled check

```
http://Just-my-IP-adress:10000
```

I would suggest using Webmin to install SSH.

In general it's a better process to build and verify your VPS in stages, testing each component before adding on another. No matter what Digital Ocean may suggest, integrating all the components together at once and flipping the switch leads to difficult to track down issues that often require you to start over and rebuild anyway.

Answer (score -1):

If you are running on azure VM you should allow inbound port 10000[image]