# Accessing webmin through browser port :10000

Tags: terminal, debian, port, webmin, server-configuration

Recently set up a Debian 9.1 x64 server with SSH and LAMP stack (PHP ver7.0). PHP and Apache are both installed correctly since I get their landing pages. UFW is also active.

I have now installed webmin(using apt-get) and also tried following the instructions from http://www.webmin.com/deb.html on a different occasion.  I "sucessfully" completed the installation(s) via terminal and it directed me to goto https://MY_Domain:10000  and to log in with root.

After multiple attempts, even tried using https://MY_IP_ADDRESS:10000 I am greeted with "Safari cannot open MY_IPADDRESS because it cant connect to the server".

I have tried the following to solve my problem:

-Reinstalling webmin,

-Restarting webmin,

-Stopping my UFW firewall,

-Allowing ports 10000 ,HTTPS port (443 I think), port 22, port22 v6

-Opening webmin config and changing the port/listen line to listen to another port such as 44321,

-Opening error logs. The only "error" that appeared was something about not being able to do something with IPv6,

-Using different browsers,

I have read many forum posts of users having similar problems but none of the solutions have been effective. I have heard of IPtables but for some reason I cannot implement that solution. Im very new to server configuration therefore I'd appreciate the help.

Similar post: [Unable to access Webmin through browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29750502/unable-to-access-webmin-through-browser)

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I finally fixed it. To fix this, log in as root then nano to

```
sudo nano /etc/webmin/miniserv.conf
```

Turn off SSL by setting it to 0.

The restart webmin and try to connect.

Im about to research into whether this is a safe practice.

Answer (score -1):

I get the same problem only after system restart. All works fine, firewall configured for webmin port and all, also tried with fireall disabled, after system restart all goes down the drain, webmin service is ufo and after uninstall and reinstall webmin the story replays. I am at my wits end. Good bye opensuse!