# Webmin does not show anything on browser

Tags: raspberry-pi, webmin

I am building a home server on Raspberry Pi 3 model A+ and am trying to set up Webmin. IP is 192.168.2.16 and the hostname is raspberrypi. Using SSH, I downloaded Webmin and ran it on port 10000, but I cannot access it on my browser at raspberrypi:10000. I can access raspberrypi, though.

I tried restarting it, reinstalling it, and changing the port number as in this post [Unable to access Webmin through browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29750502/unable-to-access-webmin-through-browser), but none of these seemed to work.

Firewall is disabled as default on Raspberry Pi, so it should not be an issue.

The port is accepting connections and I can access it through the command line, but on the browser the website never loads.

```
$ nc -zvw 3 raspberrypi 10000
Connection to raspberrypi 10000 port [tcp/webmin] succeeded!

$ netstat -an | grep 10000
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10000           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 192.168.2.16:10000      192.168.2.13:53130      ESTABLISHED
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10000           0.0.0.0:*
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessing `https://raspberrypi:10000` instead of `http` worked.